# How to tell ASCIIEncoding class not to decode the byte order mark

Tags: .net, utf-8, ascii, byte-order-mark

When decoding a byte array into a string using the .net ASCIIEncoding class do I need to write some code to detect and remove the byte order mark, or is it possible to tell ASCIIEncoding to not decode byte order mark into the string?

Here's my problem, when I do this:

```
string someString = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(someByteArray)
```

someString will look like this:

```
ï»¿<?xml version="1.0"?>.......
```

Then when I call this:

```
XElement.Parse(someString)
```

an exception is thrown because of the first three bytes: EF BB BF - the UTF8 byte order mark. So I thought that if I specify UTF8 encoding, rather than Default, like this:

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(someByteArray)
```

ASCIIEncoding would not attempt to decode the byte order mark into the string. When I copy the returned string into notepad++, I can see a ? character in front of the XML tag. So now the byte order mark is being decoded into a single garbage character. What is the best way to stop the byte order mark being decoded in this case?

Comment: Are those EF BB BF characters by any chance present in `someByteArray`? They're not ASCII, that ends at 7F.

Comment: I found a really nice explanation of this, including a class that will select the correct encoding and strip off the byte order mark as required, at this site: http://www.mobzystems.com/code/detecting-text-encoding.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don't use

```
ASCIIEncoding.UTF8
```

That's really just

```
Encoding.UTF8
```

It's not using `ASCIIEncoding` at all. It just looks like it in your source code.

Fundamentally, the problem is that your file *is* UTF-8, it's *not* ASCII. That's why it's got a UTF-8 byte order mark. I strongly suggest that you *use* `Encoding.UTF8` to read the UTF-8 file, one way or the other.

If you read the file with `File.ReadAllText`, I suspect it'll remove the BOM automatically. Or you could just trim it afterwards, before calling `XElement.Parse`. Using the wrong encoding (either ASCII or Encoding.Default) is *not* the right approach. Likewise it's *not* a garbage character. It's a perfectly useful character, giving a very strong indication that it really *is* a UTF-8 file - it's just you don't want it *in this particular context*. "Garbage" gives the impression that it's corrupt data which shouldn't be present in the file, and that's definitely not the case.

Another approach would be to avoid converting it into text at all. For example:

```
XElement element;
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    element = XElement.Load(reader);
}
```

That way the encoding will be auto-detected.

Comment: What a moment - to vote down JS for not reading a question properly...  Although you're quite right about the stylistic comment and that he shouldn't be using .ASCII.GetString(), he goes on to say he's tried .UTF8.GetString and it leaves a spurious char.  (It does too, I've just tried it in linqpad)

Comment: @Will: I was getting to that. But he still thinks he's using ASCIIEncoding, I suspect, given the title of the post. I think he's *badly* confused at the moment. I've now suggested two alternative approaches, but he really *should* be using UTF8, and he *shouldn't* be doing it via `ASCIIEncoding.UTF8` which is an abomination.

Comment: Jon - I'll take the -1 away - had my fun.  But there is something very odd (to me) here - see my other 'answer'...

Comment: Thanks Jon, the XmlReader does exactly what I want. You're also right about the "garbage character" not being garbage, but the information it represents ceratinly seems out of context in a string.

Answer (score 2):

`System.Text.Encoding.GetString()` preserves the BOM if it is present and converts it to the UTF-16 BOM (U+FEFF). Consider this a feature. Strictly speaking, it's the proper thing to do as tossing the BOM would make the conversion lossy and not round-trippable. Bit surprising, though, that they didn't provide a flag to let you specify the desired behaviour, but there you are. So...you've got two options:

1. Convert to a string, look for the BOM and remove it prior to invoking `XElement.Parse()` on the string. Or...
2. wrap the `byte[]` in a `MemoryStream`, the `MemoryStream` in a `StreamReader` and use `XElement.Load()` to do the parse.

Your choice. Here's some sample code that will work:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace TestDrive
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            byte[] octets = File.ReadAllBytes( "utf8-encoded-document-with-BOM.xml" ) ;

            // -----------------------------------------------
            // option 1: use a memory stream and stream reader
            // -----------------------------------------------
            using ( MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream( octets) )
            using ( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( ms , Encoding.UTF8 , true )   )
            {
                XElement element1 = XElement.Load( sr ) ;
            }

            // --------------------------------------------------------------------
            // option 2: convert to string, then look for and remove BOM if present
            // 
            // The .Net framework Encoding.GetString() methods preserve the BOM if
            // it is present. Since the internal format of .Net string is UTF-16,
            // the BOM is converted to the UTF-16 encoding (U+FEFF).
            // 
            // Consider this a feature.
            // --------------------------------------------------------------------
            // convert to UTF-16 string
            string       xml       = Encoding.UTF8.GetString( octets ) ;
            // Two different ways of getting the BOM
            //string UTF16_BOM = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble()).ToCharArray() ;
            const string UTF16_BOM = "\uFEFF" ; 
            // parse the element, removing the BOM if we see it.
            XElement element2 = XElement.Parse( xml.StartsWith( UTF16_BOM ) ? xml.Substring(1) : xml ) ;

            return ;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer, but code in comments is horrible, and it felt a bit rude to put this in your question.  Are you really trying to do this:

```
Byte[] bytes = new byte [] { 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF, 0x57, 0x44 };
String txt = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine("String length {0}", txt.Length);
Console.WriteLine("String '{0}'", txt);
Console.WriteLine("Chars '{0}'", String.Join(",", txt.Select(chr => ((int)chr).ToString("x2"))));
```

And wondering why you get:

```
String length 3
String 'WD'
String 'feff,57,44'
```

I certainly am...

Comment: Yes, but I didn't expect to see it in a .NET string - I would expect that to be on the byte[] side of the encoder/decoder, not the string side.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm wondering. I wouldn't expect GetString() to return information about the encoding of the file.

Comment: Because stripping off the BOM results in a lossy conversion that can't be round-tripped.

Comment: @Nicholas: Yes, you're right. Thanks for your comment, it really helped my understanding of the Encoding class's intended usage.